# Problem with widgets

Tags: widgets

I am using the theme 3Grey. It is widget enabled. There are few widgets that are hard coded in the theme. These widgets donot appear in the sidebar in the widgets page. If i try adding new widgets the old ones get deleted. Is this ths normal case. Or is there any problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most themes will have a default set of widgets that appear when you don't add any widgets yourself (using the widget page in admin).

You can normally just drag the widgets that were "hard-coded" into the correct sidebar, and all should be ok.

Comment: To add, what looks like "default widgets" are in fact not really widgets (otherwise you could see them on the widgets screen), it's just some default sidebar that is displayed as long as there are not widgets at all.